# How to create text base field without format?

Tags: 8

How to create base field without `format` surplus?

E.g. this

```
$fields['data'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('text_long')
  ->setLabel(t('XML Data'))
  ->setDescription(t('The product XML data.'));
```

creates two columns in the table:

```
`data__value` longtext,
`data__format` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET ascii DEFAULT NULL,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text (plain, long) field type is `string_long`.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21StringLongItem.php/class/StringLongItem/8.2.x